# Individually sorting subarrays of an array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, arrays

I have an array of numeric subarrays. I want to sort all the subarrays, and then sort the whole array, and remove duplicates. Using `sort($val)` doesn't work, so I found the following workaround with `$derp`, which I find insanely stupid:

```
$arr = array( array(5,6), array(1,2), array(6,5) );
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $derp = $val;
    sort($derp);
    $arr[$key] = $derp;
}
sort($arr);
$arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $arr)));
```

The result is `array( array(1,2), array(5,6) )`. Is that is the correct way to do this in PHP, or is there a better and shorter way?

I created a pastebin as a response to the first answer: [pastebin.com/Y5vNvKKL](http://pastebin.com/Y5vNvKKL)
This question is not anymore just about a less goofy way to write this: Now the question is:
Why does `sort()` in `array_work()` not give the same result as `sort()` in `foreach`?

By the way: This is about finding the [partitions of multisets](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Partitions_of_multisets).

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach it like this:

```
array_walk($arr, 'sort');

$deduped = array();
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $deduped[serialize($val)] = $val;
}

$arr = array_values($deduped);
```

Comment: `array_walk()` was what I was looking for, thanks. BTW, your code gives `array( array(5,6), array(1,2) )`.

Comment: Actually this doesn't always work in the same way as the `$derp` version. This may have to do with the fact, that my array contains not only arrays, but also single numbers. See http://pastebin.com/Y5vNvKKL

Comment: I mean: This may have to do with the fact, that the subarray contain not only single numbers, but also arrays. However, it is weird, because the code suggests that we do the same in both cases: Apply `sort()` to all subarrays. But the result is not the same.