# Sorting row values in each subarray of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like so

```
array:2 [▼
  "folder1" => array:3 [▼
    1 => "d1_2.png"
    2 => "d1_1.png"
    3 => "d1_3.png"
  ]
  "folder2" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "d2_2.png"
    1 => "d2_3.png"
    3 => "d2_1.png"
  ]
]
```

What I am trying to do is sort this array based on the value.  So the output should be something like this

```
array:2 [▼
  "folder1" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "d1_1.png"
    1 => "d1_2.png"
    2 => "d1_3.png"
  ]
  "folder2" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "d1_1.png"
    1 => "d1_2.png"
    2 => "d1_3.png"
  ]
]
```

All examples I have seen sort based on a key value, but I do not have keys.  I have tried several sort functions  but none of them seem to sort the array.

How can I sort it based on the array I have?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that my keys are indexes, not a representation.

Comment: Could the downvoters please care to comment.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26713294/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a huge number of [sorting functions in php](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), which can sort an array based on value or key, maintain index association and walk into child arrays.

What I think you want is the [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function, like this:

```
sort($array['folder1']);
sort($array['folder2']);
```

Or this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
    sort($array[$key]);
}
```

Just keep in mind. It is not the outer array you want to sort, but its child arrays.

Comment: Because I do not know the folder names I would need to go with the second option.  If I output subarray I can see that it works.  However, it does not seem to add the sorted subarray back to the original array.

Comment: Please note that I updated my answer. Just doing a `sort($subarray)` will only sort a copy of the child arrays. You will actually have to do a `sort($array[$key])`, like the updated answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
asort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
```

Comment: That is actualt one of the functions I tried, but it does not seem to sort it because I think it is doing the sort on folder1 and folder2.

Answer (score 1):

use `array_walk` (functional way of foreach) to go through the outer array and then in there use `sort`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

```
$arr = array(
    "folder1" => array(
        "1" => "d1_2",
        "2" => "d1_1",
        "3" => "d1_3"
    ),
    "folder2" => array(
        "1" => "d2_3",
        "2" => "d2_1",
        "3" => "d2_2"
    )
);

var_dump($arr);

array_walk($arr, function (&$e) {
    sort($e);
});

var_dump($arr);
```