# Sort subarray values of a 2d array and preserve first level keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I find other thread about sort multidimensional array, but it's not the same problem.

```
$arr[22][] = 45;
$arr[22][] = 44;
$arr[22][] = 99;

$arr[23][] = 95;
$arr[23][] = 55;
$arr[23][] = 1;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

I want to sort the value inside subarray, not the value between sub array.

The expected result is

```
[22] => Array [0 ] => 44 [1] => 45 [2] => 99

[23] => Array [0 ] => 1 [1] => 55 [2] => 95
```

I try with

```
array_multisort($arr[22], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC
                , $arr[23], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

but it's not correct anyway.

How could I do?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26713294/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
foreach($arr as &$v) {
    sort($v);
}
```

The `&$v` allow the values to be iterated over by reference, allowing modification inside the foreach loop (and thus sorting of each subarray).

Comment: `array_walk($arr, 'sort')` should do as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if arr is a multidimensional array
foreach($arr as &$v)
    sort($v[0]);  // sort the subarray
unset($v);
```

if you plan on using $v in another foreach later on
   any !isset($v[0]) may infect the next loop, wierd

Comment: This looks like the exact same answer that was posted as a comment over a year ago. Additionally, if the answer has a significant problem as you have described then it does not make an appropriate answer.