# Is there a native multi-dimensional, multi-type sort in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, mixed

I'm struggling with sorting a multi-dimensional, multi-type array in PHP.

Usually I just use `sort` and `rsort` and `ksort` etc.

This situation doesn't seem to require anything much more complex, but `array_multisort` doesn't appear to be working (at least not how I'm using it).

My multi-dimensional, multi-type array looks like this:

```
[
    'Welsh_Harmony' => [
        'Bread_Dip',
        'Cloud_Patterns',
        'Legendary_Sword',
        'Legumes_In_The_Garden',
        'Notice::Balloons',
        'Notice::Corvid',
        'Titanic',
        'novemberMonth',
        'Elephant_Graveyard'
    ],

    'Oak' => [
        'Keyboard'
    ]
]
```

and `array_multisort` gives me this (which is only half right):

```
[
    'Oak' => [
        'Keyboard'
    ],

    'Welsh_Harmony' => [
        'Bread_Dip',
        'Cloud_Patterns',
        'Legendary_Sword',
        'Legumes_In_The_Garden',
        'Notice::Balloons',
        'Notice::Corvid',
        'Titanic',
        'novemberMonth',
        'Elephant_Graveyard'
    ]
]
```

Whereas the result I'm trying to produce (note the position of `'Elephant_Graveyard'`) is:

```
[
    'Oak' => [
        'Keyboard'
    ],

    'Welsh_Harmony' => [
        'Bread_Dip',
        'Cloud_Patterns',
        'Elephant_Graveyard',
        'Legendary_Sword',
        'Legumes_In_The_Garden',
        'Notice::Balloons',
        'Notice::Corvid',
        'Titanic',
        'novemberMonth'
    ]
]
```

I have tried using the flag `SORT_STRING` and `SORT_ASC` to prompt `array_multisort` to alphabetically re-order and re-index the second level arrays, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I'm optimistic that there must be a way to execute this kind of multi-dimensional, multi-type sort without writing a custom, recursive function.

Comment: `array_multisort` doesn't sort all levels of an array. What you want is to sort every array inside your array with something like `foreach ($arr as &$a) sort($a);`

Comment: try to see `usort` function

Comment: Thanks, @Zeusarm - I did have a look at `usort` but it takes a custom callback and I'm concerned about performance.

Comment: @Rounin believe me it is quite fast :-) you are just comparing 2 elements. All the iterations PHP does itself.

Comment: `usort` doesn't help you either way. You're sorting the array `['Oak' => ..., ...]`, *not each value within it.* `usort` won't sort the inner values either. You need to do that explicitly.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are using

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220259/php-sort-subarray-value help?

Comment: @deceze - thanks again, I fully understand what I need now (which isn't `array_multisort`). As both you and @Oussama prompted, it's `foreach($Parent_Array as &$Child_Array) {sort($Child_Array);} ksort($Parent_Array)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> array_multisort() can be used to sort several arrays at once, or a
> multi-dimensional array by one or more dimensions.

This is basically how you sort different dimensions of your array:

```
$ar = array(
   array("10", 11, 100, 100, "a"),
   array(   1,  2, "2",   3,   1)
  );
array_multisort($ar[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
            $ar[1], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
```

Multi sort accepts variadic params. Read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), please read scroll down and read the comments.

---

Or you can loop through your array's arrays and sort them one by one.

```
foreach ($matrix as &$row) { sort($row); }
```

However, I think multi-sort would perform much better.

Comment: Aha. Thank you, Oussama. I understand `array_multisort` more clearly now. As deceze pointed out in the comments above, I had fundamentally misunderstood what the function was for.